# Get an automatic list of ExpressJS params

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I am trying to get a list of all of the parameters in a path from a get request.

`app.get('/*',function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params[0]);
    res.send('testing');
});`

However, when I go to the url `localhost/test/test1`, the `params[0]` object is `'test/test1'`.

Is there any way to make it split the url in to params without doing `'/*/*'`. I want to be able to put in as many values as I need without worrying about naming or counting them.

The ideal input/output would be:

`URL: localhost/arg1/arg2/arg3
params[0] = 'arg1'
params[1] = 'arg2'
params[2] = 'arg3'`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will work:

```
var splitParams = params[0].split('/');
```

Comment: I was going to try this but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to keep it in the params object.